# Need advice for how to structure my data in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, firebase-security

So I am trying to figure out the best structure for my use case.

**Currently it looks like this**:

```
salesItems | userId | salesItem1 | 
                    | salesItem2 | and so on.
```

So the items are stored in a document named with the respective userid.

**The problem with this is**, that I am expecting this document to get bigger than 1MB.

So I thought maybe I need to setup collection group queries.

Therefore I set up a structure like this:

```
salesItems | userId | StoreA | documentId | startDate: 
                                          | endDate: 
                                          | salesItems:

                    | StoreB | documentId | startDate:
```

Where items get stored as chunks in a document, which get start- and enddate as fields to make it possible to query these chunks by date.

So a document would look like this:

```
 startDate: 01/01/2021
 endDate:   12/31/2021
 salesItems:[items]
```

My goal is to query all documents across all stores for a user.

**So my questions are:**

1. Do you think there is a better solution?
2. If you also think I should go with collection group queries,
   what would be the correct security rule?

After watching fireships [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fQ4u1J717ys&t=139s) on collection group queries, it seems like there are special security rules needed for collection group queries.

Currently I am writing :

```
match /salesItems/{userId}/{documents=**} {
  allow read, write: if true; //No restriction for testing purposes.
}
```

but that doesn't work.

Here is a screenshot of the current structure.

**NOTE** I need to store items in the **2** box. I plan to remove the **1** row, but thats not part of the question.

[image]

This is the subcollection structure I came up with:
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify the structure (exactly what is being stored in each collection) with a screenshot of sample documents? The terminology is a bit confusing like `salesItems` collection has documents with `userId` and then has salesItems again in sub-documents.

Comment: I have uploaded a screenshot.

Comment: Just to understand the data. Is it like - there are users and each of them can have multiple stores and then each store has it's own items (salesItems)?

Comment: Pretty much, yes.

Comment: I have added another screenshot with the subcolletion structure I was thinking of

Comment: I've posted an answer with an example of security rules for collection groups queries but please change them as per requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a stores and items data, you can try structuring your database as shown below:

```
users -> {userId}
(col)     (doc)

stores -> {storeId} -> items -> {itemId}
(col)       (doc)      (col)     (doc)
```

You can store a field `ownerId` in each store document to reference the user who owns the store (or an array of UIDs if a store can have multiple owners).

This way you can query items from a specific store as well as by item ID of any property in item document using CollectionGroup queries.

---

I'm not sure about what permissions you required on these collections but for collection group queries you can structure them as shown below:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {

  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow anyone to read items
    match /{path=**}/items/{itemId} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }

    // Allow users to read but owner to write store
    match /stores/{storeId} {
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner;
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

---

Additionally, the items sub-collection can also be a root level collection. Then you would have to add a field that contains storeId in it as well but then there would be no need to use CollectionGroup queries.

---

**Edit:**

Since each can have their own data of each store, the following structure can be used:

```
users -> {userId} -> stores -> {storeId} -> items -> {itemId}
(col)     (doc)       (col)       (doc)      (col)     (doc)
```

You now have a store document for each user any information about that store can be stored in the store document. While `items` can be an array as mentioned in the original question, it might be easier to to query those if stored in a sub-collection since there isn't any `unwind` like functionality in Firestore.

Comment: Okay, I am starting to understand a little better. However there is one thing I failed to make clear: Each user has its own "instance" of a store. 

I am collecting data from a specific store, with an API for the users account. 
For example: I am logging in to a users Shopify account and get the data from there. 
So there are never 2 users that have access to the same store"instance". 

Do I still need to store the `ownerId` in the documents then?

Comment: @Christian if I understand correctly, so lets say there is a store StoreA and 2 users - user1 and user2. They both can have a document associated with StoreA? Like StoreAUser1 and StoreAUser2?

Comment: I am web scraping data for my users accounts at StoreA & StoreB. So user1 gives me his credentials for StoreA, I am scraping data for his account, and store it under `salesItems - userId1 - StoreA`

If user2 wants me to scrape StoreA with his credentials, I would store it under `salesItems - userId2 - StoreA`

But these 2 results would have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @Christian I've updated the answer, can you check that?

Comment: That structure looks perfect. However, would I be able to query items across all stores?

Comment: @Christian you could list all stores of a user but if you want to run a collection group query on items sub-collections then you would have to store user Id in each item document so you can specify it in the query.

Comment: That sounds good, thanks for your patience!